# Cannot load tensorflow saved model back

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation#export_the_generator

And i use the following code to save the model and load it back, the saving part works but when i load the model and use "remodel.summary()" i get the following error

```
tf.saved_model.save(one_step_model, 'one_step')
remodel = tf.saved_model.load('one_step')

Error -> AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

I believe this means the model wasn't loaded? why is that happeneing? the model does get saved properly and i followed everything in the tutorial

Also I have another question, doing this would make it possible for me to re-use the model without needing to train it again right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
model = create_model()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

model.save('saved_model/my_model')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')


new_model.summary()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey, it did not work. i get another error like this...

Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1, None), dtype=int64)
        * None
        * True
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}

     Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):